# How to catch errors in multer

Tags: node.js, multer

I have read documentation for multer. But the current set up I have in my code is different and this makes difficult for me to understand how to handle errors.
It is important now because it happened (only once) that a file was not stored on the server but the code continued saving info in database as if the storing of the file had worked. But it probably did not.

```
const multer = require('multer');

var docPath = "path_to_disk_where_to_store_files";

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    inMemory: true,
    destination: function (request, file, callback) {
        callback(null, docPath);
    },
    filename: function (request, file, callback) {
        //Just a function that creates an unique name with timestamp
        renamedFile = helpers.createUniqueName(file.originalname);
        callback(null, renamedFile);
    }
});

var fileFilter = function (req, file, cb) {
    var path = require('path');
    var ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    if (file.mimetype !== 'application/pdf' || ext.toLowerCase() != '.pdf') {
        req.fileValidationError = 'goes wrong on the mimetype';
        return cb(null, false, new Error('goes wrong on the mimetype'));
    }
    cb(null, true);
};

const multerUploader = multer({storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter, limits: { fileSize: maxSize }});

router.post('/save_document',[multerUploader.single('file'),saveDocumentInDb]);
```

I dont really understand where the if-statement that will check if the upload got an error would fit.

Answer (score 10):

Please refer the following for error handling when using multer:
https://github.com/expressjs/multer#error-handling

Your implementation will be something like this:

```
const multerUploader = multer({storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter, limits: { fileSize: maxSize }});
const upload = multerUploader.single('file');
router.post('/save_document', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
    } else if (err) {
      // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
    }

    // Everything went fine and save document in DB here.
  })
})
```

Comment: thank you. it's a very nice implementation.

Comment: can you tell me what is correct response error is on these two cases?

or in another word, what is the best error status in case of multer error and other error that you named it unknown error